# How to effectively wait for a file to unlock?

Tags: delphi, winapi

In my thread code I need to wait for a file to be unlocked in order to process it further.

The file is potentially locked by another foreign thread(s) which I can't control.

Currently i use this code in my thread:

```
...
while IsFileInUse(FileName) and not Terminated do
begin
  Sleep(100);
end;
// process the file
```

`IsFileInUse` code:

```
function IsFileInUse(const FileName: string): Boolean;
var
  Handle: HFILE;
begin
  Handle := CreateFile(PChar(FileName),
    GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  Result := (Handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
  if not Result then
    CloseHandle(Handle);
end;
```

Is there a better and more efficient way to avoid the `Sleep`?

Comment: Since my comments are somehow removed I'll repeat. I don't like the dupe because of the answers there. The accepted answer: 1st solution suggests killing processes that holds a handle to the file - not an efficient way to avoid sleep. 2nd solution suggests waiting on processes that holds a handle to the file -  not efficient, they may release the handle before they terminate. 3rd solution suggests opening a read handle and asynchronously  wait for a lock - not efficient, 1- you may not get a read handle, 2- it's possible to have a write access without an exclusive lock and you won't know it.

Comment: The other answer does not even answer the question.

Comment: I can imagine another application using a similar approach to monitor the same file you are, and you'd end up fighting with it over that file. Imagine that file is released from whatever was holding it up, then you confirm it's usable, so you try to read it and BAM the other app got to it first. This is why I like the Windows messaging system, because things become sequential and prioritized, rather than luck of the draw. Too bad there's no direct API for this purpose. Something simple like `MonitorFileState()` passing the filename and callback procedure. Maybe even `OpenFileWithWait()`

Comment: You can use LockFileEx if you can previously open the file with sharing enabled, https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no API that would make it possible to be notified when opening a file becomes possible. Programs that monitor this kind of activity (e.g. ProcessMonitor) use a file system driver ([link](http://www.decuslib.com/decus/vmslt00a/nt/filemon.htm)).

Consider giving up on a test opening of the file though, as it introduces a possibility that the file becomes unavailable again in between a test opening and actual opening for processing.

Comment: Your second point here is almost more important than your first one.